# Trigger to count the number of related Records(look up - Not Master Detail)

Tags: apex, trigger

I have a Custom Object - `Vendor_Contract__c`.
Another custom object `Work Allocation`. It is looking up to object `Vendor_Contract` (Vendor Contract to Work Allocation is 1 to many relationship).

I should not be able to delete a Vendor Contract when there is any related Work Allocation present.
I don't know where my code is breaking. I am not getting the desired error.

Please have a look into my code and any advice is appreciated

```java
public class LabContractTriggerHandler {
    public static void checkWorkAllocation(List<Vendor_Contract__c> LabContractList, boolean isDelete){
    
        Set<Id> listLabCont = New Set<ID>();
        for (Vendor_Contract__c ven: [SELECT ID, (SELECT ID FROM Work_Allocations__r) FROM Vendor_Contract__c WHERE Id IN :LabContractList]){
            if(ven.Work_Allocations__r.size()>0){
                listLabCont.add(ven.Id);
            }
        }
        for(Vendor_Contract__c venCont:LabContractList){
            if(listLabCont.contains(venCont.Id) && isDelete){
                venCont.addError('You cant delete a Labor Contract with Work Allocations. Please delete the Work Allocations before deleting the Labor Contract');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: welcome to SFSE! Please take a moment to visit the [help], scroll through the [tour], and read [ask]. What have you debugged and where is this method being called from (ex. After Delete trigger)?

Comment: I checked the Object settings. It says that : 

What to do if the lookup record is deleted? | Don't allow deletion of the lookup record that's part of a lookup relationship.



I'm getting this error which doesnt make sense:

There's a problem saving this record. You might not have permission to edit it, or it might have been deleted or archived. Contact your administrator for help.

Answer (score 0):

Trigger can look like this:

```
trigger TriggerName on SObject (before delete) {
    TriggerHandlerClass.checkChildren(Trigger.old, Trigger.operationType.name());
}
```

And handler class can look like this:

```
public with sharing class TriggerHandlerClass {
    public static void checkChildren(List<SObject> recordList, String operationType) {
        if(operationType.contains('DELETE')) {
            for(SObject record : [SELECT Id, (SELECT Id FROM ChildRelationship) FROM SObject WHERE Id IN: recordList]) {
                if(record.ChildRelationship.size() > 0) {
                    record.addError('Error message');
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In this specific case we do not have to pass operation type as parameter & check it, but if your trigger is triggered not only on delete event, you will have to check operation type

Comment: Thanks Arnas for your help. But you see, this code is not bulkified. Also, I'm still getting the error. But appreciate your help and thoughts.

Comment: It is bulkified trigger. You can try to delete large amount of records and it won't exceed government limits.
Salesforce cancel all operation if Trigger Exception is raised with addError method

Comment: [Trigger exceptions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_exceptions.htm)